# How to keep asking for a console input running even after program execution

Tags: java, console

I am trying to execute a program after taking user input from the console. [code block below]. However, I do not want to terminate after the program execution finishes. I want the console to always ask me the INITIAL_MESSAGE after the execution finishes. Effectively, after the execution of the program, I want the console to again ask me the INTIAL_MESSAGE so that I can again enter the inputs as I want and execute the program again. 
I am actually calling the interactor() in this method, from the main method as the starting point. 
Please tell me how do I achieve this

```
public class ConsoleInteraction {

    /**
     * @param args
     */

    public static int numberOfJavaTrainees ;
    public static int numberOfPHPTrainees ;
    Barracks trainingBarrack = new Barracks();


    public void interactor() throws IOException {

        //reading capability from the consolemessages properties file

        ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources/consolemessages");

        // Create a scanner so we can read the command-line input
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Prompt for training or viewing camp       
        System.out.print(bundle.getString("INITIAL_MESSAGE"));
        //Get the preference as an integer
        int preference = scanner.nextInt();


        //Show options based on preference
        if(preference == 1)
        {
            //System.out.println("Whom do you want to train?\n 1.Java Guy \n 2.PHP Guy \n 3.Mix \n Enter You preference:");
            System.out.print(bundle.getString("WHO_TO_TRAIN"));
            int traineepreference = scanner.nextInt();
            if (traineepreference == 1)
                {
                //System.out.println("How many Java guys you want to train ? : ");
                System.out.print(bundle.getString("HOW_MANY_JAVA"));
                numberOfJavaTrainees = scanner.nextInt();
                trainingBarrack.trainTrainees(numberOfJavaTrainees, 0);

                }
            else if (traineepreference == 2)
                {
                //System.out.println("How many PHP guys you want to train ? : ");
                System.out.print(bundle.getString("HOW_MANY_PHP"));
                numberOfPHPTrainees = scanner.nextInt();
                trainingBarrack.trainTrainees(0, numberOfPHPTrainees);

                }
            else if (traineepreference == 3)
                {
                System.out.print(bundle.getString("HOW_MANY_JAVA"));
                numberOfJavaTrainees = scanner.nextInt();
                System.out.print(bundle.getString("HOW_MANY_PHP")); 
                numberOfPHPTrainees = scanner.nextInt();
                trainingBarrack.trainTrainees(numberOfJavaTrainees, numberOfPHPTrainees);

                }
            else 
                {
                    System.out.print(bundle.getString("ERROR_MESSAGE1"));
                }
        }
        else if (preference == 2)
        {
            System.out.println("Showing Camp to You");
            System.out.println("Java trained in Trainee Camp : "+ TraineeCamp.trainedJavaGuys);
            System.out.println("PHP trained in Trainee Camp : "+ TraineeCamp.trainedPHPGuys);

        }

        else 
        {
                System.out.print(bundle.getString("ERROR_MESSAGE2"));
        }   

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a loop around your call...?!

Comment: A for loop around the call from the main method? How long should I continue the call ?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do... you could interactor return boolean and make that the loop condition. And if initial messagebid "quit" return false?

Comment: ANy sample code please ?

Comment: Will take me some minutes - coding on smartphone sucks :-)

Comment: :) shall wait . Thanks for the efforts Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider these changes quickly drafted to your class. Might not compile. Might not work as you planned.

Some highlights of what I think you should change:

- Use constants for the choice values. Makes your code way more better to read.
- Initialize Bundle and Scanner outside of the method. Might be reused.
- instead of coding lengthy parts of code inside of the if-else-if cascade, call methods there - angain increasing your readability a long way

  ```
  public class ConsoleInteraction  {

    public static int numberOfJavaTrainees ;
    public static int numberOfPHPTrainees ;

    //Don't read that every time...
    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources/consolemessages");


    public static void main(String[] args) {
      //Moving Scanner out of loop
      try {
          Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
          ConsoleInteraction ci = new ConsoleInteraction();
          //Loop until this returns false
          while(ci.interactor(scanner)) {
              System.out.println("=== Next iteration ===");
          }
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

   }

  //Constant values to make code readable
  public final static int PREF_TRAINING = 1;
  public final static int PREF_SHOW_CAMP = 2;
  public final static int PREF_QUIT = 99;

  public boolean interactor(Scanner scanner) throws IOException {

      // Prompt for training or viewing camp       
      System.out.print(bundle.getString("INITIAL_MESSAGE"));
      //Get the preference as an integer
      int preference = scanner.nextInt();

      //Show options based on preference.

      if(preference == PREF_TRAINING) {
          //LIKE YOU DID BEFORE OR calling method:
          readTraining(scanner);
      } else if (preference == PREF_SHOW_CAMP) {
          //LIKE YOU DID BEFORE OR calling mathod:
          showCamp();
      } else if (preference == PREF_QUIT) {
          //Last loop
          return false;
      }  else {
          System.out.print(bundle.getString("ERROR_MESSAGE2"));
      }   
      //Next loop
      return true;
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Jan for the inputs. I got the drift here. Thanks for your efforts